# Communication with two agents within a single block in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

As seen below in my flowchart I am trying to model jobs that are being sent to servers. In the service block, my resource pool is servers.

My current model has Agent 'Jobs' being created in the source. they are then sent to the Queue and to the Service block where the Service block will seize a server(Server Agent) from the resource pool.

I have set out my simulation so that servers are deleted at random times.

[image: Anylogic Flow Chart]

My trouble is:  When a server that is currently working on a Job is deletes (at a random time), how is it possible to send the Job back to the queue.

I'm having an issue getting the service block/server pool accessing the Jobs agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're deleting your servers but if you're doing so by reducing the capacity of the resource pool my answer will work as you desire.

For you to return the job back to queue, first you'll need some changes to your flowchart. (See Image)

[image]

Then, in your service block, change your settings to match mine:

[image]

And voilá, that's it. If you're using a different type of deletion and this approach doesn't work, let me know.

Cheers,
Luís Pereira